# Prisma order posts based on likes

Tags: javascript, prisma

I have a Post model:

```
model Post {
  id      String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  title   String
  content String
  likes   Like[]
}
```

And a Like model:

```
model Like {
  id        String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  user      User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId    String   @db.ObjectId
  postId    String   @db.ObjectId
  post      Post     @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id])
  likeType  LikeType
}

enum LikeType {
  like
  dislike
}
```

I want to order posts based on the number of Likes (not dislikes) a post receives.
Something like:

```
prisma.post.findMany({
    orderBy: {
      likes: {
        _count: {
          where: {
            likeType: "like",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort by a relation from [2.19.0](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/releases/2.19.0) by aggregates including count.
But it's currently [not possible](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/5079) to return the count of a relation itself.
Separating the models for likes and dislikes simplifies the query pattern.

```
const orderedPosts = await prisma.post.findMany({
  orderBy: {
    likes: {
      count: 'asc'
    }
  }
})
```